# Laravel + InertiaJS + Vue 3: Play transition on page BEFORE navigation with Link, button, etc

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, transition, inertiajs

**TL;DR:** In a Laravel + InertiaJS + Vue 3 developed application, how can I achieve to have a transition between "pages" loaded within a persistent layout `<main>` section - for example, have that section animate (say, fade out) before loading the next page, then animate (fade) that new page in - when using standard Inertia routing for navigation? I have managed to do it ***on entering/showing*** the page, but have found no way to animate before navigation happens.

**LONG(ish): The Way I'm trying to do it**

Let's assume there is an application (developed with Laravel + InertiaJS + Vue 3).

I have an element in the markup of an Inertia persistent layout that is conditionally shown if a value is true (v-if="shouldAnimate") that is initially set to `false` when declared, and when `onMounted` fires, it sets that value to `true` which in turn triggers the animation to run (doesn't really matter how the animation works, but just in case, I have options to use either GSAP or anime.js).

Up to this point, all is good: every time I navigate to a page (using Inertia-adequate methods such as the `Link` component) the animation triggers and I am a happy guy.

BUT: I would very much like to be able to **play another animation (the reverse of the previous one) before, say, navigation to the next page occurs.** I have tried almost everything I can think of and have not been successful. Here's what got the closest to what I need:

I tried hooking into the InertiaJS event `Inertia.on('before', ...)`: effectively, the event fires up right before navigation (checked with some good-old console log), so I tried firing up the animation at this point, only to find out that the Inertia event looks like it is destroying the page immediately before the animation has had time to play; no problem: I'll just `event.preventDefault()` it, run the animation and THEN, using a `setTimeout` timed to the length of the animation (300ms) I'll resume navigation, say, by using `Inertia.visit`.

Doesn't work. Somehow, the default behaviour is prevented (stops the navigation), the animation plays back, but when it comes to the "resume navigation part" I have had mixed results depending on what I use:

Code looks roughly like this:

```js
let removeListener = Inertia.on('before', (event) => {
    
    event.preventDefault()

    // Play animation here

    setTimeout(() => {
        // SOME INERTIA ACTION DESCRIBED BELOW
    }, 300)

})
```

Independently of whether I use `Inertia.get(event.detail.visit.url)` or `Inertia.visit(event.detail.visit.url)` what happens is the animation runs its course, and then the timer runs out and this whole code RUNS AGAIN AND AGAIN in intervals equal to the timer. I also tried to do this using the `complete` event of the animation to trigger the navigation but it behaves the same.

I know this is related to me being an ignorant about how both Inertia and events work, and I am sure there is a proper (correct? right?) way to achieve what I need, but either I have failed in using the correct terms to look for it, or I am approaching this the wrong way. Hopefully this information is enough to explain my issue.

Any help or pointer would be GREATLY appreciated, so thanks in advance.